# Openstreetmap (osm), how to create map for my DB? Description inside

Tags: database, openstreetmap

How is it possible to cut some area on the osm (display only city/country or smth similar)? And when user will be near to the ground, he will see more and more: streets, then maybe shops etc. Then I will put it in the DB, that I have, and user will get the map in the app from my DB. But question is: where (what program) can help me to cut the area and do everything, that i described; or how I can do it on the osm site?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the zoom event on your map. On different zoom level, you display/hide your (base)layers.

Have a look on this example : http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/examples/0000-viewer.html#/layers/overlays-hide-on-zoomout-example